# Convert HTML textbox in complete readonly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Requirements: Make textfields readonly - not disabled , user shouldnt be able to click on the field even once (more or less textfield should behave like select box). Also user when presses tab should be able to move to next field(normal behavior) Internet Explorer should be the browser for rendering the code.

Sample code which I have been doing is here

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" value="test1" onfocus="this.blur()" readonly="true" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" value="test2" onfocus="this.blur()" readonly="true" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" value="test3" onfocus="this.blur()" readonly="true" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The problems with the above code are 
1. User is able to click once (blinking cursor is visible) 
2. On pressing Tab - user doesn't move to next field.

Again only for IE. Thanks

Comment: Why can't you use the disabled option? Seems to fit the bill.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To address the tabbing issues, you'll probably need to add `tabindex` to the inputs:

```
<input type="text" value="test1" onfocus="this.blur()" readonly="readonly" tabindex="1"/>
<input type="text" value="test2" onfocus="this.blur()" readonly="readonly" tabindex="2"/>
<input type="text" value="test3" onfocus="this.blur()" readonly="readonly" tabindex="3"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

I would say that if you need something that's readonly, and must not behave like a form element, then, you should not use a form element : just use the value as a text :

```
<tr>
  <td>test1</td>
</tr>
```

This way :

- It doesn't behave like a form element,
- No-one will think one should be able to modify it

If necessary, you can then use a bit of CSS to style it, with a border, for example...

Answer (score 2):

This will let you tab into each textbox, but they won't let you click on them.
Use the onclick event to blur it and set the readonly attribute to prevent editing.

http://jsfiddle.net/aQvGx/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `disabled`. It solves the tab index issue

```
<input type="text" disabled="disabled" />
```